# search items that load data from DB in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, search, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

In my application, I have an observableArray that loads data from DB. This observableArray fills first 25 items from DB and from scrolled down it loads another 25 and it goes on.

Now, I want to implement search, that should display the result searching the whole data from DB and not just from the displayed 25 items.

I tried to get the search result by sending the whole searching text to DB on clicking search button and there is lot of datas in DB which takes much time to load data.

Please let me know how I can get the desired result from DB within ms. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your API already support search?

Comment: I have just sent the search term to web api service and binded the result back to the observableArray... It take more than 40 secs to load the data.

Comment: on initial load of page in controller end get all the list and store it a `list` and when you performing search do a `Linq` on list and return matches ones via ajax . That should be very quick . flooding db with req's is never a smarter option(until unless your db data changes dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

To get a well behaving search with Knockout, you should extend your `searchText` observable that is bound to the input with a [rate-limiter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html)

```
this.searchText = ko.observable('').extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } })
```

This will call any subscribers after the input has remained unchanged for 500ms (i.e. when the user stops typing). You could also use the default method `notifyAtFixedRate` to call the API at least once every X seconds.

And to top it off, a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyWebb/p5wrqrfb/)!

**Note:** with this being said, if your query is taking 40 seconds, that sounds like a problem with your database query. It's possible that it's taking that long because you're flooding the server with requests, but that still seems awfully slow. This is the strategy we use and it works excellent, but our API response time is <200ms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. The fiddle you posted doesnt work when i entered 'Assembly' in it.. Which term i have to enter to look its working...

Comment: For some reason that example isn't working in Safari, but it does seem to work just fine in Chrome and Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I believe that has to do with CORS and JSFiddle. `$.get` can be fragile, so converting it to a regular `$.ajax` call and passing all the correct headers should make everything work cross-browser. If the API is on the same domain, you shouldn't have any issues.